# How to use the count iif function to count how many students passed in access?

Tags: ms-access, count, percentage

I am supposed to count how many students passed and show the answer in a text field on the form. I've tried =Count(iif([Results]=>50, 1, 0)) but it is not working. The results field is in percentage.

Comment: count is counting everything, 0, 1, -1, 10, 23, and so on. But is not counting null. So I would suggest using sum instead of count. Or use null instead of 0 if suitable.

Answer (score 0):

another simple way to do this:
the Result column is named (StudentResult).
success is from 50 or larger.

```
        Try
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE StudentResult >= @myval"
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myval", "50")
                Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                dt.Rows.Count = textbox1.text
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("error : " + ex.Message)
        End Try
```